# How do I find the tangent of an equation, when the $x$-coordinate is $1$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the tangent to the graph $y = x^2 + 4x + 3$, whose $x$ coordinate is $1$.
Write your answer in form $y = mx + c$

I got the equation $y = 2x^2 + 2x + 2$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

$$y=x^2+4x+3$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+4$$
At $x=1$, *y* is 8 and the derivative is 6, so write
$y=mx+c\rightarrow8=6(1)+c$; we get $c=2$. Hence the tangent at $x=1$ is $y=6x+2$.

Comment: Beat me by a couple of minutes. GG

Answer (score 0):

The other answer tells you how to do the problem but does not address something you are clearly confused about.

When a question asks you to find a tangent to a curve, you are being asked to find the a linear approximation to a function at a point, which is why you take the slope of the tangent curve to be the derivative of the function or curve at that point; the derivative is the limit of secant lines from points on either side of the point in interest. In your case, this is $x=1$.

I am not sure how you got your expression, but no, it is not in the form $y=mx+b$. It is important to know the difference between a *linear* equation that lies and a quadratic equation. The equation you provided is not a line.